Eevee Next - Data Transfer Normal Blending?
I upgraded my Blender install from 4.1 to 4.2 last night fully aware that Eeevee Legacy (AKA Eeevee in versions <=4.1) was rewritten into Eevee Next to support raytracing. By and large I'm very impressed with Eeevee Next but it has caused the artistic intent of some of my existing projects to suffer.

Above you can see a GIF of how one of my character rig .blend files looked in the Blender 4.1 Eevee Material Viewport. I use the 'Data Transfer' modifier on the chest mesh to make the chest and torso mesh normals appear to seamlessly blend into one another as though one continuous topology flow. I've used the 'Data Transfer' modifier excessively in projects from the last few months for exactly this purpose.

Now, reading the same .blend file in Blender 4.2 and viewing the rig in the Eevee Next Material Viewport, you can see the illusion I created is broken because of these cavities of darkness generated by GI/AO when Raytracing is enabled. I'd rather keep raytracing on because in 4.1 I had 'Screen-Space Reflections' enabled in all the scenes of all my .blend files which has been replaced by true raytraced reflections in Blender 4.2, so what I discovered is that cranking the GI/AO bias all the way to 1 almost entirely fixes this problem with only a small compromise to Raytracing.

This is where I'd hope the problems would end, but that's not so. Now, on the other side of the chest mesh, we have this shadow being cast that is also breaking the illusion.

With the 'Soft Shadows' option also being gone in the transition from Eevee Legacy to Eevee Next which masked this problem entirely in Eevee Legacy, the only fix I can see for this is to turn shadows off entirely in Eevee Next.

Now sure, technically the illusion is now restored, but look at what I've had to lose to get there! I've managed to salvage reflections at the cost of no GI/AO but I've lost the ability to cast shadows entirely, my renders now look worse than they did in Blender 4.1. I totally understand that asking for Eeevee Next to be more like Eevee Legacy is a square peg in a round hole, but all the same I think it's unreasonable to expect people such as myself to stick to Eevee Legacy in 4.1 and miss out on all the amazing stuff Blender 4.2 and onwards will have over some trivial quirks in the rewrite that is Eevee Next. What can I do to bring this illusion back to life in Eevee Next without all the compromises I've had to make to get there?
